# getAttribute of dom object calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I am using [jqueryui.com's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default) function and I would like it to add the values in a datalist if the input has the list attribute and a remote json source if it has the src attribute.

As far as I can tell I should be able to do:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".keywords" ).autocomplete({
        //determine dom object that called this
        //if dom object has list attribute
            //walk though dataset with id = list attribute
                //add to source
        //elseif dom object has src attribute
            //add url data to source
        }
    });
});
```

but I am not very familiar with javascript, how would I extract the dom object, then test it's attributes?

Comment: I'm surprised that after asking 44 questions, you couldn't format your own code. If you don't know how, just highlight the code, and click the **`{}`** code sample button at the top.

Comment: +1 whoops, forgot. thanks.   Usually not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it *directly* like that, but you could do this:

```
$( '.keywords' ).each(function() {
  var field = this;
  $(field).autocomplete({
    blah: $(field).attr('blah'), // etc
  });
});
```

You don't *really* need the "field" intermediate to hold the `this` value, but I think it makes things a little less confusing in cases like this.

Comment: +1 Woo, good one, so I can now switch data sources. all I need now is to figure out how to walk the datalist